# Does the code swap two numbers of the array?

Tags: c++

An '&' should be included in the actual parameters to give the required result, but the following code also swaps the numbers correctly.How?

```
void swap(int *a, int *b){

    int t=*a;
    *a=*b;
    *b=t;

}

//there is an array ar[]
swap(ar[0],ar[1]);
```

It should give some garbage values but it is giving the correct answer.

Comment: If it compiles then `ar` is very likely an array of pointers or an array of arrays.

Comment: The code as is should not compile unless `ar` is a `int*[]`.  Please provide a [mcve]

Comment: Prefer [std::swap](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/swap) over reinventing the wheel.

Comment: You wrote `using namespace std;` somewhere, didn’t you?

Answer (score 0):

There is a possibility that the function call is actually calling the library-defined `std::swap` function and not your custom swap function(because of types not matching).

Change the name of your function and see whether it compiles or not.